# Creating a menubar

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to make a menubar with unorder list.My problem is when i put float left on the .left class and float right on the .right class the background I have put before on 'ul' just disappeared. How can i fix this??
Is there any other way to keep the background with the floating classes??

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}
li.left{
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
li.right{
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
       <ul>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="right"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="right"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set some height `height: 200px;` to ul tag, because your `ul` tag has `height` 0.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
li.left{
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
li.right{
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
       <ul>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="left"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="right"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
         <li class="right"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
```